# React Redux share data across the component no parent child relation

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I take a list from API, it takes time to fetch all records. I want to make an API call when the user is logging, within the login component I want to store the response data and want to send it to the component where it should be listed.

I installed React redux for state management and I am having difficulty with passing data from one component to another.

**Installed packages**

```
npm install react-redux
npm install redux
npm install @reduxjs/toolkit
```

**`Login.js`**

```
let data = [array of objects]
  

 loginUser(event) {
  const loginUser = {
    password: this.state.password,
    id: this.state.userID,
  };
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL}login`,
    data: loginUser,
    withCredentials: true,
  }).then((res) => {
    if (res.data.isSuccessful === "yes") {
    
      this.setState({
        loadingScreen: true,
      });
      // Here I want my data accessible across all component 
      setTimeout(
        function () {
          this.props.history.push("/Home");
        }.bind(this),
        5000
      ); 
    
    } else {
      this.setState({ isErrorPassword: true });
    }
  });
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You installed redux but are not using it anywhere in your code, your code only uses local state. Maybe read about [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#basic-example) and [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#hooks)